# Help understanding the password file

Tags: oracle, linux

I have one database and password file
Now I'm creating a new database, do I need to create another password file or not?

I'm a beginner in Oracle, maybe a bit stupid question.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password file is an option for authenticating remote users with special privileges. A database can operate without a password file. So no, it is not mandatory.

Typically all databases have their own seperate password file. If you create the new database with DBCA, that automatically creates the password file for the new database.

Some companies simply do not create password files for their databases and disable password file authentication in order to lower security risks. Think of it as disabling root login through SSH.

Features like Data Guard rely on password file authentication. You can create the password time now or later, it is up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, I did not find this in the documentation.

Comment: In addition to what Balazs said, I mostly use a password file for remotely authenticating the sys user. One case where it helps is when you duplicate and Oracle database, you could connect target as sys to the source database and auxiliary as sys to the target database. In this case you would need a password file. You can also do a restore and rename as a duplicate database. But you can't have two databases with the same name running from the same Oracle Home on the same server.